# Transfer learning with Keras and CNN: Received a label value of 46 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, transfer-learning

I have trained a Sequential model with a dataset having 43 classes; each class name is 0 - 43 and they're derived from the directories' names. Now I want to use transfer learning to create a new model on top of the previously trained model, with the new data having classes of 43 - 47. Now the problem is when I add 5 (the count of my labels 43-47) as number of classes in the Dense layer it shows this error:

***tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 46 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).***

So how do I add the number of classes in the Dense layer starting from 44, not zero (0)?

Here is my transfer model code:

```
model_old = load_model('model.h5')

model_new = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

for layer in model_old.layers[:-1]:
    layer.trainable = False
    model_new.add(layer)

model_new.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax"))
model_new.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if your call the tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=None, dtype='float32') function that converts your Y vector contating labels (43-47) into a matrix of integers from 0 to num_classes = 5 in your case (0,1,2,3,4).
Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Hello @wmsr, thanks for the contribution, but doing so the values will be overlapped with the first dataset matrix integers which are 0 - 4 for (0,1,2,3,4) classes. and this one will also be (0,1,2,3,4) that I don't want it to be like this because I have a dictionary for all the labels like:  `1: 'Speed limit (20km/h)',
           2: 'Speed limit (30km/h)',
           3: 'Speed limit (50km/h)',
           4: 'Speed limit (60km/h)',
           5: 'Speed limit (70km/h)',
           6: 'Speed limit (80km/h)',` and I want different names for 43, 44, 45, 46 and 47 classes

Comment: Hi @sadaf, the 5 output classes of your new_model are completely different from the 43 output classes of your old_model. I.e: when you perform predictions with the new_model you w'll get an y_pred vector containing probabilities to belong to one of the (43-47) classes. On the other hand, If you need predictions for the 43 first classes you'll probably use the old_model to perform it. so for the new_model labels are {'43':0, '44' :1, ... , '46':4}, and for the old_model labels are {'0':0, '1':1, ..., '42':42}.

Comment: Hi @wmsr thank you so much! It's solved. :)